# Is there a list of known MMA bugs, fails, and work-arounds somewhere?

Tags: discussion

I ask because MUCH to my distress, MMa returns wrong results for the equation that's the entire basis of Fourier Analysis and hence most of Filter Theory, the integral of products of cosines:

[How to force correct answers for Integrals of Cos[mx]*Cos[nx]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65951/)

The post received lots of Comments about generic/non-generic solutions, with links to other posts about similar issues, but no reliable work-around yet.

The strange part is that comments say it's unfeasible for MMa to handle all the obscure special cases, but this particular result is HUGELY important, not an obscure case at all.  A lot of important stuff bombs of MMa gets this particular equation wrong.

So is there a list somewhere of problems like this so I can plan around them?  A list with links to suggested work-around would be great, too.  If such a list does not exist, it needs to exist and be accessible from this site.

Comment: Have you looked at the [tag:bugs] tag?

Comment: @rm-rf  I don't think Wolfram considers this a "bug" because MMa is doing what was intended. Strictly speaking I guess it is a horrendous design oversight not a bug.  Still, a page of other known issues/bugs with work-arounds would be helpful.

Comment: @JerryGuern This is not an official Wolfram site and the `bugs` tag is not applied based on feedback from Wolfram.  It's added when the users of this site agree that something is a bug.  Many of these questions have answers describing workaround.  It seems it's precisely what you're asking for.  (But please let's not make this question about the particular issue you mentioned: personally I don't agree that it's a bug for reasons Daniel mentioned in the comments.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Which Questions are you talking about describe the workaround? The ones people linked in comments? I saw some solutions there that can only be used if I anticipate the problem and plan around it.  So, I'm still asking, is there a list somewhere of the known MMa bugs and failures?  Is there a way to Search through Questions based on tags?  And what tag would be used for situations like this one, where the failure is not considered a bug?

Comment: @JerryGuern yes it is possible to search through questions based on tags. For example if you click this -> [tag:bugs] you will see a list of questions with the tag bugs (you could also have followed the link provided by rm-rf). You can also search a tag, see for example [this query](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbugs%5D+integrate).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom  I followed that link, from rm-f too.  It does not lead to a list of Questions.  It says "You are on the Featured tab. There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" But there's no indication of how I might select a different tab.

Comment: That does not happen to me. I get the bugs list that Jacob intended, with currently 422 questions listed. Perhaps something with the configuration of your browser? You could try a different browser to see if that helps.